# Differentiate a send and a receiver with actioncable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I currently use actioncable, but I am facing a problem, I would like to create an messenger app I would like to put the recipient on one side and the senders of the other.
For exemple :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhsHI.png)

So the objective is to make a comparison between the sender and the connected user but the problem is that the views used by actioncable only know the variables that we sent him. so the view can only take the sender user instance.

Anybody have a method to exclude sender to receive broadcast ?

I can also do that

```
    all_users_except_sender.each do |user|
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_#{user.id}", message: html_message)
end
ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_#{current_user.id}", message: html_message_for_sender)
```

or put sender as html attribut and detect message from other user with erb javascript
but i don't think it's good practice

Comment: Does the `html_message` contain the full chat partial view?  (including the contacts on the left and the messages on the right; basically are you rerendering the whole thing?) or does it only contain the "new" message, and then you have a JS that adds/inserts this message to the right pane?

Comment: No html_message is just a partial of my message `<li class="replies"><p><%= message %></p></li>` and for the sender partial i just change class to "sent"

Comment: Since you are rendering the views through ActionCable, I think I'll do the same thing as you did like `all_users_except_sender ... ActionCable.server.broadcast` because the "rendering of the views" is handled by the backend-side and not the js-client-side. I don't think there's a way to exclude the sender (magically), because the sender is agnostic of the "pub-sub"; that is if a client is subscribed to `"chat_19"`, then it normally receives all data broadcasted to `"chat_19"` regardless if it's the same user or not. You'll need to do something like what you have above.